# Can't access Textbox.Text in UWP application

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I am tinkering with UWP app and I encountered a problem with my ContentDialog Textbox. I can't access it even though I declared x:Name here is my XAML

```
<ContentDialog

x:Class="Quickstart.Sadd"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="Add Student"
PrimaryButtonText="Add"
SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick">
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox x:Name="Nam"  Text="Name" Width="300"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="SNam" Text="Surname" Width="300"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>

</ContentDialog>
```

and my c++ code

```
#include "Sadd.g.h"

namespace Quickstart
{
[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
public ref class Sadd sealed
{
public:
    Nam->Text;
    StudentRe^ stdnt;
    Sadd();
private:

void 
ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialog^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs^ args);

void ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialog^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs^ args);
};
```

}

the compiler acts like he doesn't know what "Nam"(This declaration has no storage class or type specifier) is even though I specified its name in XAML. I think it might be because I am using namespace, but tutorials for UWP written in c++ are sparse, to say the least, and I think I run out of options besides asking here

Comment: Did you come around this code https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-access-a-control-6039571a/sourcecode?fileId=137957&pathId=1717760240

Comment: @cloudikka no i haven't seen that but i don't know how this could help me, in this example you can use normal names like tbVideoInde->Text->Data() and i don't see anything special in code that would allow that

Comment: I dont understand why are you using ContentControl instead of using StackPanel directly as a content of ContentDialog. What is the benefit of it?

Comment: You could not access TextBox  with `Name` in the `DataTemplate` directly  , For your requirement , you could use `Binding` to realize this feature.

Comment: `public: Nam->Text;` isn't valid. Do you want `Platform::String^ name;` maybe? And then to bind the `TextBox` to that value later?